# Worklight Studio plug-in for Indigo in Windows 7

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo, ibm-mobilefirst, eclipse-marketplace

I cannot seem to get Worklight to install properly. I am using Windows 7 32 bit Operating System and a clean installation of Indigo(eclipse-jee-indigo-win32). When trying to install Worklight from Help -> Eclipse Marketplace

I got the following message:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed

```
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.support.ie,1.0.500.v20130201_1508.
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/plugins/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.support.ie_1.0.500.v20130201_1508.jar
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.etools.attrview,1.0.100.v20120918_0208.
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/plugins/com.ibm.etools.attrview_1.0.100.v20120918_0208.jar
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.etools.webtools.dojo.library,1.0.600.v20130222_1636.
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/plugins/com.ibm.etools.webtools.dojo.library_1.0.600.v20130222_1636.jar
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.etools.webtools.views,7.0.400.v20120918_0238.
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/plugins/com.ibm.etools.webtools.views_7.0.400.v20120918_0238.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.imp.webtools.dojo.library.distributions,2.0.0.v20130222_1636.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: f684f4987bf9c1c8fd7a11b0e236c696 and found ebfb1b8103c514843cfa6df80943b177.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.imp.worklight.simulation.ui,1.0.300.201303110941.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 0365031246d3315fa96efeea94516084 and found b188214e58bf88bb7ea89f88e08c6d2c.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.worklight.worklight-builder,5.0.6.20130311-0918-developer-edition.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 8dc2626664d5e6a2e04ee222602ba13d and found 2205fbf0b7dfd192232aba0e9eda0820.
```

When I tried to Install again from Help > Install new software(By adding Worklight Studio - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/).
I got the following messages in the add new software window:
Coudnt find http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/

Is anyone else seeing a (new) problem installing Developer Edition from the Marketplace in Indigo???

Comment: I don't think http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/ is an Update Site.  Try it again with Indigo SR2, or better, Juno SR2.

Comment: But I get to see ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight site in every get started with the Worklight guides(http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/library/mo-aim1206-working-with-worklight-1/)...Please let me know which is the Updated site if not this.

Comment: An "Update Site" is a REPOSITORY URL you use WITHIN ECLIPSE. The URL  you mention is the HOMEPAGE of IBM Worklight. Use this repository URL in Eclipse: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/

Answer (score 1):

You have to install this version:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr2

"IBM Worklight Developer Edition on Eclipse Marketplace only supports Eclipse version 4.2.2 (SR2), Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers edition. If you install on earlier versions or different editions of Eclipse you will see errors."

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct repository URL (or a repository URL at all...).
Use this URL:

> http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/

Before doing so, make sure your Eclipse Java EE 3.7 (Indigo) installation is up-to-date.
Go to Help >> Check for updates. However, I strongly recommend starting fresh using a new installation of **Eclipse Java EE  4.2.2 (Juno SR2)**.

Comment: @Arjan Tijms : I installed  **Eclipse Java EE 4.2.2 (Juno SR2)** freshly and tried to add the plugin...Still i am facing same issue :(